# Build Trigger doesn't recognize Negative Lookahead in RegExp on Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm using Cloud Build as a CI/CD solution. My branching strategy follows this pattern: `dev`, `stage` and `prod` branches reflect exactly what I have in each of my environments. Any other branch is just a regular branch for development.

By following this pattern, I need to build/test in any branch except the main ones, and deploy only when pushes are in dev/stage/prod.

As Cloud Build doesn't support expressing this in a single YAML file, I have two: `build.yaml` and `deploy.yaml`.

Then I created two Build Triggers, like this:

[image]

The first works just fine, it triggers the steps described in `deploy.yaml` if anything is pushed to `dev/stage/prod`. But the second, although it accepts the RegExp and evaluates a preview of branches (notice you don't see the main branches):

[image]

When the build gets triggered (yes, it is triggered automatically!), it fails:

[image]

A bit of Googling tells me Go-lang (which supposedly is the back-end where this regexp is being evaluated here) does not support Lookahead in RegExp.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally there is a new feature on cloud build to address this issue, basically on the triggers options there is a checkbox called `Invert Regex`, here is how it looks like:

[image: invert-regex-checkbox]

This basically means that branches or tags matching the regex are excluded and by using `^(master)$` combined with this `Invert Regex` you will be able to match any branch that is NOT `master`.

Comment: This option looks like it exists only when editing a trigger, not when setting up a new trigger via setting up a new Cloud Run service.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I solve this problem?

Here is how I did it, after trying negative look ahead first.

e.g. exclude branch `master`

```
^(([^m]|m($|[^a]|a($|[^s]|s($|[^t]|t($|[^e]|e($|[^r]))))))|master.+)
```

More details [here](https://lustforge.com/2018/11/07/cloud-build-triggers-excluding-branches/).

Comment: That works, but I can imagine how the UI would be with a regex three times longer than this in order to accommodate our three main branches. But I appreciate, the answer is correct.

Comment: @larruda, I agree. It's hack, but I'm sure better controls are in the works.

Comment: Seems like they finally added an option to solve this, there is a new checkbox called `Invert Regex` that basically will cause any matching branch/tag to be excluded.

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno, thanks. When that feature is GA, I'll update this post.